# Printing variable which was taken from other class in other page

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, pyqt5

I tried to explain my problem as much as I could.

I can edit if you need.

```
class calculating:
    def __init__(self,username,password,url):
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.url=url

    def connectingTowebsite(self):
        r=request.get("self.url")
        # I achived number1 and number 2 by connectingTowebsite
        return number1,number2

    def sum(self):
        number3,number4=self.connectingTowebsite()
        # There are some calculating process here
         number5=(numbers3+numbers4)
         return number5

    def addingtodatabase(self,divisionnumber):
        # Then user send a number and methods' jobs are over
          number6=(self.sum() / divisionnumber)
          sql_query=("INSERT INTO SOMETHİNG.....")
          values=number6
          return number6
          # Now I want to use the number6 in a class in another page.



#this is another python file\secondpage.py
from firstpage import calculating
import sys`
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class showingvalues(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# I have some codes here for my window and login process
# and a textedit to show the variables from firstpage\calculating

     def calculate(self,divisionnumber):
         result=calculating("myUsername","myPassword","myUrl").addingtodatabase(divisionnumber)
         return result

     def calculateSaveAndShow(self):
    # User enter a divisionnumber
    # Number1 and Number2 which have already taken from website by request
        self.calculate("a division number from user") # I am using PyQt5 to get that.
```

Then all process over.

Dates has been inserted into database

I want to show the value which has been just saved  on textedit on  my application window

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: I have a class which scraps websites and collect some data and user gives a digit and another method calculates them and saved into database. I am trying to designer by Qt Designer. I want to add a textline into my application and show the user what saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

I would store number6 as a property in your first class then you can just access it directly in your second class.

so in your `addingtodatabas` method:

```
self.number6 = number6
```

Then in `showingvalues` class you have access to it as:

```
number6 = calculating.number6
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that functions are already returning the values, you just need to assign it to a local variable.
Change `self.calculate("a division number from user")` to:

```
number6 = self.calculate("a division number from user")
```